# Get depth of node in binary tree using iterative DFS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree, depth-first-search

With recursive DFS on a tree, it is possible to get the depth of any node by passing the depth in as a parameter to a recursive function. However, with non-recursive DFS, I am not sure how to get the depth of a node.

I have a basic DFS template setup, but I can't figure out what to change in order to return the depth of the target node.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def dfs(root, val):
    stack = [root]
    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        if node.val == val:
            return node
        if node.left:
            stack.append(node.left)
        if node.right:
            stack.append(node.right)
```

I found this solution: [Depth of a tree using DFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659337/depth-of-a-tree-using-dfs) but it seems to be using a different way to store the tree and it also seems to require knowing the entire tree beforehand.

Comment: Hint: `stack = [(root, 0)]` and `node, depth = stack.pop()`

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. In a recursive DFS you pass in the depth as a parameter, here you pass it in through a tuple. For some reason I thought I could have a single global variable tracking the depth of the current node, but it seems like that is not possible.

Comment: You almost can (by keeping track of the direction you’re going), but I don’t think it saves anything unless nodes have a reference to their parent as well.